# How to prevent pDialog getting closed on clicking outside the dialog area

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng

I am using pDialog from primeNg. In my case the dialog gets closed when i click from mouse outside the dialog. How can I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog

[image]

Se the dismissableMask property as per the documentation.

Comment: tried this already but not working.